# Как установить C# версии 7.2?

Tags: c#

Хотел потестить модификатор доступа private protected (готовлюсь к зачёту), но пишет, что это доступно только в версии 7.2. В VS максимально доступная для меня версия 7.1. Пробовал скачать Rider, но и там нужна версия 7.2.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47328622/6766879

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас Visual studio 2017 то обновите её до 15.5 и будет вам C# 7.2 в комплекте.

[Where is c# 7.2 in visual studio project settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47328622/5752652)

[image]