# Как подключить кортежи для C# в MVS17?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Как подключить кортежи для C# в Visual Studio 17?

Comment: Студия [обновлена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/838172/213987)? Какая у вас версия студии, а то может у вас C#7 нет.

Comment: А где можно посмотреть версию студии и шарпа? Вроде как вчера или позавчера скачивал с сайта майков коммьюнити версию 17-ой студии.

Comment: Версия студии 15.7.5, версию шарпа не нашёл.

Comment: В билд сеттинге проекта указана последняя основная версия [C# latest major vesrion (default)]

Comment: *могу ли я положить в кортеж, скажем, string и map?* - можно что угодно. Во первых версия языка должна быть не ниже 7.0 (Properties - Build - Advanced - Language Version), во-вторых версия .NET должна быть не ниже 4.7 (Properties - Application - Target framework), на более старый фреймворк можно подключить NuGet-пакет: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/

Comment: @АндрейNOP понял, у меня стоял дотнэт 4.6

Comment: Ну и, кстати, старые/обычные кортежи вы можете и так использовать: `var myTuple = Tuple.Create(10, 5);` Скажите, что конкретно вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Я про новые `(int, string) tuple = ( index:0, name:"string" )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы кортежей необходим **C#7** и **.NET 4.7**.

Информацию о текущей версии языка можно посмотреть в <kbd>Project</kbd> - <kbd>Properties</kbd> - <kbd>Build</kbd> - <kbd>Advanced</kbd> - <kbd>Language version</kbd>. Для использования *C#7* необходима студия 15-ой версии и выше [MVS17].

[image: Project - Properties - Build - Advanced]

Узнать версию текущего фреймворка можно в <kbd>Project</kbd> - 
<kbd>Properties</kbd> - <kbd>Application</kbd> - <kbd>Target framework</kbd>. Там же можно установить новую версию *.NET*, выбрав <kbd>Install other frameworks</kbd>.

[image: Project - Properties - Application]

Для старых версий .NET можно подключить [NuGet пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/), позволящий использовать кортежи.